# How to set the value of a variable in one function with the returned value from another function?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I am extremely new to postgresql and do not understand how to set the value of a variable in one function with the value from another function. This is as far as I have got:

**Function A**

```
CREATE FUNCTION functiona(_postid integer) RETURNS integer
        LANGUAGE SQL
    AS
$$
BEGIN
    SELECT posttypeid
    FROM post
    WHERE postid = _postid;
END;
$$;
```

**Function B** (which calls Function A to get value)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION functionb(_postid integer DEFAULT NULL) RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE _posttypeid int;
BEGIN
    IF _postid IS NOT NULL
    THEN
           _posttypeid := select functiona(_postid); -- want to set value of _posttypeid to the value that comes from functiona
    END IF;
END;
$$;
```

In **Function B**, how do I set the value of `_posttypeid` to be the value that gets returned from **Function A**?

Comment: First why not have just one function? Two the first will not work as it is `LANGUAGE SQL` and that does not support `BEGIN/END`(that is for `LANGUAGE plpgsql`).

Comment: `_posttypeid := functiona(_postid);`